# Вмятина с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

столкнулся с проблемой, главная беда в том, что очень тяжело сформулировать на словах что мне именно нужно, поэтому прилагаю скрины того чего нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и то, что у меня сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хватает вмятины между словами, как такое реализуется в вебе????

Comment: если фон "серый квадратик" - картикой, то нарисуй там

Comment: Нет, фон - небольшой градиент,но идею понял, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-разному можно

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body > div {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  display: grid;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #717074 0%, #a59fa0 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

div > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div > div:first-child {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px white;
}

div > div:last-child {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Target</div>
  <div>$15</div>
</div>
```